# Have these two words 牵 and 千, 感 and 敢 the same tone?

Tags: tones

Google Translate shows the same phonetic annotation `Qiān`. Have these two words the same tone, the high tone `ā`?

```
牵 Qiān = Hold (hand), Lead (by hand)
千 Qiān = Thousand
```

Google Translate shows the same phonetic annotation `Gǎn`. Have these two words the same tone, the falling-rising tone `ǎ`?

```
感 Gǎn = Feel, sense, touch
敢 Gǎn = Dare
```

Google Translate shows the same phonetic annotation `Zài`. Have these two words the same tone, the falling tone `à`?

```
再 Zài
在 Zài
```

Comment: You don't need to update your question with more questions of the same type. Just paste the characters into an online dictionary and it will tell you if the tones are the same.

Comment: imrek’s answer here (https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14596/how-many-syllables-does-chinese-have) reveals only 1522 different pinyin syllables (tones considered). The average educated Chinese person knows around 8000 characters. By the pigeonhole principle, words that share pinyin syllables with the same tone *must* happen.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they have the same pronunciation in Mandarin, including the tone. For questions like these, checking a dictionary would have given you the right answer immediately.

Comment: Olle Linge Some dictionary makes/contains mistakes, or printing errors. It pays to ask, or confirm with, people that are knowledgeable on the questions for free, as the OP did.